# How to include gems in the project using Rails 2 and Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: grails-2.0, ruby-1.9.3, grails-2.3, grails-2.4, grails-2.2

I have the project built using

```
Rails 2.3.18
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
```

I do not have any Gemfile  my project so how include gems in it.

Answer (score 0):

edit the app/config/environment.rb

```
config.gem 'will_paginate', :version => '~> 2.3.16'
config.gem 'ssl_requirement'
config.gem "ambethia-recaptcha", :lib => "recaptcha/rails", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```